# LINQ Orderby Descending Query

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by

I have a LINQ query that I want to order by the most recently created date.

I tried:

```
var itemList = from t in ctn.Items
                    where !t.Items && t.DeliverySelection
                    orderby t.Delivery.SubmissionDate descending
                    select t;
```

I have also tried:

```
var itemList = (from t in ctn.Items
                     where !t.Items && t.DeliverySelection
                     select t).OrderByDescending();
```

but this gives an error :

```
No overload for method 'OrderByDescending' takes 0 arguments
```

From what I've read, the first way it should work. I've tried changing `descending` to `ascending` just to see if it does anything but it stays the same.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 762, accepted):

You need to choose a Property to sort by and pass it as a lambda expression to [`OrderByDescending`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534855(v=vs.100).aspx)

like:

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.Delivery.SubmissionDate);
```

---

Really, though the first version of your LINQ statement should work.  Is `t.Delivery.SubmissionDate` actually populated with valid dates?

Comment: Hi optus, thanks for your reply. I've figured out what the problem was. I was using a paginatedList, and it was actually doing the ordering from that helper class. I'll mark your answer as correct once the time limit is up :)

Answer (score 210):

I think this first failed because you are ordering value which is null. If Delivery is a foreign key associated table then you should include this table first, example below:

```
var itemList = from t in ctn.Items.Include(x=>x.Delivery)
                    where !t.Items && t.DeliverySelection
                    orderby t.Delivery.SubmissionDate descending
                    select t;
```

Comment: include is equivalent to 
DataLoadOptions dlo = new DataLoadOptions();
dlo.LoadWith<Items>(i => i.Delivery);
ctn.LoadOptions = dlo;

Answer (score 33):

I think the second one should be

```
var itemList = (from t in ctn.Items
                where !t.Items && t.DeliverySelection
                select t).OrderByDescending(c => c.Delivery.SubmissionDate);
```

Comment: I think to be fair to him, I had typed the query wrong when I posted (ie. Leaving in the second last orderby line) and he probably just copied and pasted to demonstrate the use of the lambda OrderByDescending.

Answer (score 13):

Just to show it in a different format that I prefer to use for some reason:
The first way returns your itemList as an System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable

```
using(var context = new ItemEntities())
{
    var itemList = context.Items.Where(x => !x.Items && x.DeliverySelection)
                                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Delivery.SubmissionDate);
}
```

That approach is fine, but if you wanted it straight into a List Object:

```
var itemList = context.Items.Where(x => !x.Items && x.DeliverySelection)
                                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Delivery.SubmissionDate).ToList();
```

All you have to do is append a .ToList() call to the end of the Query.

Something to note, off the top of my head I can't recall if the !(not) expression is acceptable in the Where() call.