# asp.net mvcscaffolding Postscontroller.cs sort to order by decending

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

```
    //
    // GET: /Posts/

    public ViewResult Index()
    {
        return View(postRepository.AllIncluding(post => post.Comments));
    }
```

I want to modify the code above to display in reverse order by PublishDate column.

Answer (score 1):

Examples can be found here:

1. [MSDN LINQ Samples](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)
2. your problem seems similar to this [answered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344805/linq-orderby-descending-query) on OrderByDescending

Comment: Thank You..I have found a solution that work for me 
            var sort = from x in db.Posts select x;
            sort = sort.OrderByDescending(x => x.PublishDate);
            return View(sort.ToList());