# LINQ: adding OrderBy to query

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I'm at the finish line for my university project, and I'm kinda stuck at finishing a query.
The working query looks like this:

```
var Report = from query in Document.Descendants("order")
                         group query by query.Element("seller").Value
                            into qGroup
                            select new Orders
                            {
                                Seller = qGroup.Key,
                                Quantity = qGroup.Sum(p => int.Parse(p.Element("quantity").Value)).ToString()
                            };
```

I would really appreciate it if you can show me, how to Order the results by the given "Quantity" in descending order.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you really need 'ToString()' on the Quantity assignment?  Looks like it should be a numeric value.

Comment: Hello Tim! Yes, I need it to be string, because of further code usage, that I haven't posted.

Answer (score 3):

```
var Report = (from query in Document.Descendants("order")
              group query by query.Element("seller").Value into qGroup
              select new Orders
              {
                  Seller = qGroup.Key,
                  Quantity = qGroup.Sum(p => int.Parse(p.Element("quantity").Value)).ToString()
              })
              .OrderByDescending(order => order.Quantity);
```

Comment: Oh my... @Tim Croydon was actually right. I made a little change in my class, and removed "ToString()" and everything works like a charm! Thanks a lot to both of you!

Answer (score 0):

Please do this :

```
var Report = (from query in Document.Descendants("order")
                            group query by query.Element("seller").Value
                            into qGroup
                            select new Orders
                            {
                                Seller = qGroup.Key,
                                Quantity = qGroup.Sum(p => int.Parse(p.Element("quantity").Value)).ToString()
                            }).OrderByDescending(x => x.Quantity);
```

HTH !!!!

(Kudos to [LINQ Orderby Descending Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344805/linq-orderby-descending-query) )

Answer (score 0):

The answers by Skippy and Andrei work, but you can also write as

```
var Report = from query in Document.Descendants("order")
             group query by query.Element("seller").Value
             into qGroup
             let qty = qGroup.Sum(p =>int.Parse(p.Element("quantity").Value)).ToString()
             orderby qty descending
             select new Orders
             {
                 Seller = qGroup.Key,
                 Quantity = qty
             };
```

if you'd rather keep it all in one syntax.

Comment: Thanks, I did the modification as you suggested and its perfect now. Thanks for that alternative syntax as well!

Comment: No prob.  If you've found any one of the answers useful then please accept it - that's how StackOverflow works.  You may also want to look at the 'homework' tag definition too ;-)

Comment: I actually spend a lot of time here. Its just that I don't like to be the one asking questions, because I do know how to search for what I need. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find that, so I signed up. ;-)