# List Tuple DateTime

Tags: c#, linq

I have a  variable `List< Tuple< DateTime, double>> myList`.
Given a `datetime`, hope it returns the `Tuple` that precedes 
the `datetime` by using `Linq`.
For example, `if "2013-Feb-08 21:34:00"` is supplied, want to
see the last Tuple in the list whose datetime is before this `timestamp`.

How do I do this with `Linq`?

Edit:
myList.Where(t => t.Item1 < timestamp).Last();
solved my issue.
Which is better in terms of performance compared to
myList.TakeWhile(t => t.Item1 < timestamp).Last();

Comment: use [.OderByDescending](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344805/linq-orderby-descending-query)

Comment: the element I want might not be the first one in the orderby list.

Comment: By "last", do you mean the item with the highest index in the list, or the item with the highest `DateTime` value?

Comment: each Tuple was added in temporal order, so the highest index would be the one closest to the supplied datetime.

Comment: Why are you using tuples? I think anything with human-readable property names will be better

Comment: To add with what @lazyberezovsky said, a [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) may be a much better data structure than a List too.

Comment: @AlvinWong: It looks like sorting *is* required - the way I understand the question, given an arbitrary key, the OP wants to find the latest entry with an earlier key.

Comment: How important is performance here? Is this a really large list? (The existing solutions are O(N) or worse, but we can easily get O(log N)

Comment: the list is populated in temporal order so no sorting is needed. The list is at most some millions and performance is not so much a concern. but the faster the better.

Comment: @Chris *where + last* cannot be better than *takewhile + last*, because where enumerates whole sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [MoreLinq](http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview) MaxBy (available from NuGet):

```
myList.Where(t => t.Item1 < timestamp).MaxBy(t => t.Item1);
```

Or (if items are sorted):

```
myList.TakeWhile(t => t.Item1 < timestamp).Last();
```

---

UPDATE (with binary search) write comparer:

```
public class MyComparer : IComparer<Tuple<DateTime, double>>
{
    public int Compare(Tuple<DateTime, double> x, Tuple<DateTime, double> y)
    {
        return x.Item1.CompareTo(y.Item1);
    }
}
```

Then search

```
   int index = myList.BinarySearch(new Tuple<DateTime, double>(timestamp, 0), 
                                   new MyComparer());

   if (index == 0)
      // there is no items before timestamp

   if (index > 0)
      result = myList[index - 1]; // your item is previous

   if (index < 0) // no tuple with date equal to timestamp
      var nearestIndex = ~index;
      if (nearestIndex > 0)
          result = myList[nearestIndex - 1];
```

Comment: @AlvinWong you can't use binary search with `IEnumerable` sequence (which also is not sorted). It enumerates all items, but does not use internal storage to store them all ordered. It simply takes one max item.

Comment: Oh it seems that my brain get confused by comments suggesting using `SortedDictionary`. Seems that the OP should really use it and write his own binary search algorithm.

Comment: @lazyberezovsky Got compile error: MaxBy is not defined in System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<<System.Tuple<System.DateTime,double>>>. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: @Chris you should add `MoreLinq` package from NuGet (btw consider second option if you have ordered sequence)

Comment: @Chris both solutions with LINQ have 2*O(N). Use last solution with binary search for speed O(log N)

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = myList.OrderByDescending(t => t.Item1)
  .SkipWhile(t => t.Item1 > timestamp)
  .First();
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the best performance, you should not use LINQ at all. A binary search gives the performance O(log n) intead of the O(n) that LINQ can offer.

Create a comparer for your type:

```
public class MyListComparer : IComparer<Tuple<DateTime, double>> {

  public int Compare(Tuple<DateTime, double> x, Tuple<DateTime, double> y) {
    return x.Item1.CompareTo(y.Item1);
  }

}
```

Use the comparer with the [`BinarySearch` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ftfdbfx6.aspx):

```
int idx = myList.BinarySearch(new Tuple<DateTime, double>(new DateTime(2013,2,8,21,34,0), 0), new MyListComparer());
if (idx < 0) {
  idx = (~idx) - 1;
}
Tuple<DateTime, double> item = myList[idx];
```

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: The difference is that O(log n) is less than O(n), thus better performance.

Comment: I asked about difference between my and your answers :) MyListComparer vs MyComparer

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: No, you thought that you asked about that. ;) There seems to be no difference between the implementations.

Comment: Well, I think you did it without knowing about my update, thus +1 from me (but you forgot to check if idx > 0) :)

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: I assumed that there will actually be a possible match. *Every* LINQ solution presented here will throw an exception if there isn't any match.

Answer (score 0):

myList.Where(t => t.Item1 < datetime).OrderByDescending(t => t.Item1).Last();