# Entity Framework query ignoring my orderby

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

I have myself this SQL query

SELECT
`db_accounts_last_contacts`.`id`,
`dbe_accounts_last_contacts`.`last_contact_date`,
`db_accounts_last_contacts`.`description`,
`db_accounts_last_contacts`.`follow_up_date`,
`db_accounts_last_contacts`.`spoke_to_person_id`,
`db_accounts_last_contacts`.`account_id`FROM
`db_accounts_last_contacts` ,
`db_companies`
WHERE `db_companies`.`id` =  `db_accounts_last_contacts`.`account_id`
ORDER BY `db_accounts_last_contacts`.`last_contact_date` DESC

Which returns my results ordered by last_contact_date.

Now I have my Entity framework query

```
var query = (from c in context.accounts_companies
             select new AccountSearchResultModel()
             {
                 LastContacted = (from calc in context.communique_accounts_last_contacts
                                  where calc.account_id == companyId
                                  orderby calc.last_contact_date descending
                                  select calc.last_contact_date).FirstOrDefault()
            });
```

However when I go ahead and do my ToList on it, my results are never ordered
Here is my table un-ordered
[image]

Here is my list ordered using the SQL query
[image]

Why isn't my entity framework query not picking up my orderby? Or if it is why am I always pulling out the first one?

Comment: And what SQL is generated? Baseline debugging please. It may also help to provide version numbers of the relevant software - which is EF in this case.

Comment: TomTom the query above is a snippet of my query, if I paste my whole query in sql using my debugger to see the SQL my sql is over 600 lines so not sure if I can post my SQL code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry for the late answer,

What I had to do in the end was create a view and import it via the EDMX file and then use that to pull out my results.

Answer (score 0):

You need to choose a Property to sort by and pass it as a lambda expression to OrderByDescending
like this:

```
.OrderByDescending(x => x.calc.last_contact_date);
```

I hope this helps.

[Linq Orderby Descending Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344805/linq-orderby-descending-query)

Comment: I have triedLastContacted = (from calc in context.communique_accounts_last_contacts
                                                  where calc.account_id == companyId
                                                  //orderby calc.last_contact_date descending
                                                  select calc.last_contact_date).OrderByDescending(x => x.Value).FirstOrDefault()

However it didn't take effect