# Data from SQL view in entity collection are not sorted

Tags: entity-framework-6, sql-server-2008r2-express

I have a simple SQL view with 2 columns. First is the primary key, which is an nvarchar, and the second is an int. View is ordered by the int column. When I load data using EF, data is not sorted how is specified in SQL. What do I need to do to receive correctly sorted data?

Comment: ORDER BY int column ASC or ORDER BY int column DESC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ORDER BY is effectively ignored in a view. You need to specify ORDER BY in the actual query you use against the view. See the following for an explanation.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66353/why-is-the-order-by-clause-in-a-view-ignored-as-soon-as-its-called-with-a-where

Comment: I was hoping that I will get better answer than message from SSMS. There is no other query that queries view. That link does not provide any reasonable proof why ORDER BY is not working and should not be used in view.

Comment: Sorry, but that link does explains why ORDER BY is ignored. Perhaps you should research what a view is and how SQL is used to query a view.

Comment: When ORDER BY is used in these objects, the clause is used only to determine the rows returned by the TOP clause - does not work. A view, being a table expression (a set), can't have the order defined, since that would be against the principles of a relational model - This is the reason why it cannot be ordered? LOL

Comment: Precisely! But, if your view is called MyView, then when you query against it you can use `SELECT * FROM MyView ORDER BY SomeColumn` and you will get the results in the correct order. Annoying, i agree!! :0)

Comment: Because I am using Entity Framework thus I am avoiding any direct use of SQL language.

Comment: If you specify an orderby clause in your Linq queries (eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344805/linq-orderby-descending-query) it will get translated into ORDER BY in the corresponding SQL. I feel your pain ... currently engaged in an EF vs DataGrid battle myself!

Comment: I think I will try to set default sorting in XAML using CollectionView.

Comment: That will work, but bear in mind that EF doesn't necessarily load all the records at once (lazy loading), so unless you intend to load your entire dataset in one go (using Linq.Include for instance), the sorting will only apply to the records you have already loaded.

Comment: I have lazy loading turned off and everything that is needed is loaded in ViewModel. I don't know about any automatic additional data loading on DataGrid. It is desktop application.

Comment: If you've turned lazy loading off then you should be fine :0)