# C# LINQ return counter array indices max to min

Tags: c#, linq

A newbie with C# and LINQ.
I have an array which is essentially a counted sequence.

> {1,3,5,2,7,2}

I am trying to write a query that returns list of indices with highest values in descending order:

> 4,2,1,3,5,0

I can get the maximum index with this query below, but I can't seem to work out how to get the next indexes in sequence with a single query.

```
int index = array.ToList().IndexOf(array.Max());
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq Orderby Descending Query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344805/linq-orderby-descending-query)

Comment: @OldFox - That's not a duplicate at all.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works:

```
var list = new [] {1,3,5,2,7,2};

var indices =
    list
        .Select((n, i) => new { n, i })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.n)
        .Select(x => x.i)
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks, Enigmativity!

Comment: @tarzan - If you like my answer don't forget to click the accept tick. :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `Select`:-

```
var result = numbers.Select((v, i) => new { Value = v, Index = i })
                                .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
                                .Select(x => x.Index).ToArray();
```

[Working Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/4kttXU).