# Store name + number and sort in size order based on the numbers

Tags: c#, arrays, list, sorting

Doing a college project and I'm a bit stuck..

Basically, I need to take the string input for an employee name and an integer input for the amount of properties they sold.

I then need to print these values in descending order based on the number of properties sold, so, for example, I need to print something like this:

(Bolded to make it easier to read)

**Name**: John **Properties Sold**: 5

**Name**: Peter **Properties Sold**: 4

**Name**: Craig **Properties Sold**: 3

I have stored the name and properties sold in their own separate lists, I know how to sort the number list in size order but then how do I link it back with the appropriate name?

```
    List<string> names = new List<string>();
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

    for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){

      Console.WriteLine("Please enter the employee name: ");
      names.Add(Console.ReadLine());

      Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of Properties Sold: ");
      numbers.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));        
    }

    numbers.Sort();
    numbers.Reverse();

    foreach(int i in numbers){

    Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

Any help is appreciated, I am not the best coder so sorry if I'm asking a dumb question.

Comment: Do you know what a struct is? you could use those? Is there any constraints that the teacher gave you?

Comment: ↑ or a class, IMHO would be better suited. **Edit**: Actually looking at your code again, a Dictionary<string, int> would suffice, no need for other types

Comment: Eh structs are lighter weight than classes and you don't need methods. But for something like this, it doesn't really matter.

Comment: I have actually never used a struct, but I can do some googling now thanks for your advice (no constraints given by teacher based on what we can use) @IanKirkpatrick

Comment: Why not a Dictionary? A new struct is overkill. Dictionarys associate a key with a value. You would just be replicating this data structure in your struct.

Comment: @Josh see my comment ↑

Comment: @ilostmyshoes looking at your track record, it would be best to up-vote and or accept any answer's that helped you, that's how you say "thanks" here.

Comment: Another option instead of a class or struct is to use tuples.  Either the generic class `Tuple<T1, T2>` or in c# 7 value tuples `List<(string Name, int Properties)>`

Comment: A word of advice: do not use `int.Parse` unless you *already know that the string is an integer*. It will crash your program if it is not an integer. The correct way to turn user input into an integer is `TryParse`.

Comment: Dictionaries and tuples work great for a simple project like this, but sometimes it's better to just create a class (which takes *very* little effort). Often, as projects grow, it becomes necessary to add new properties and/or methods (like overriding `ToString()`), inherit a base class (`Realtor` may inherit `Employee` as a base class), or implement an interface; in which case `Tuple` and `Dictionary` no longer make sense. Just something to think about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you would be using a class for these, as seen in the example below.

```
 public class Owner
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public int PropertiesSold { get; }
    public Owner(string name, int propertiesSold)
    {
        Name = name;
        PropertiesSold = propertiesSold;
    }
}
```

This way you can keep track of the name and # of properties at the same time. Your loop turns into this:

```
 List<Owner> owners = new List<Owner>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
        {

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the employee name: ");
            string name  = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of Properties Sold: ");
            int numProperties = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            owners.Add(new Owner(name, numProperties));
        }
```

And you can use Linqs OrderByDescending as seen here to sort the list of Owners. [LINQ Orderby Descending Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344805/linq-orderby-descending-query).

Comment: This is the method I went for in the end, thanks for this!

Answer (score 2):

Probably the easiest way is to store the values *together* in a single list, by creating a simple class to hold them:

```
public class Realtor
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int PropertiesSold { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can populate instances of this class from the user input, add them to a list, and then use the linq extenstion method `OrderByDescending` to order the items by the `realtor.PropertiesSold` property:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var realtors = new List<Realtor>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var realtor = new Realtor();

        Console.Write("Please enter the employee name: ");
        realtor.Name = Console.ReadLine();

        realtor.PropertiesSold = GetIntFromUser(
            "Please enter the number of Properties Sold: ", x => x >= 0);

        realtors.Add(realtor);
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    realtors = realtors.OrderByDescending(realtor => realtor.PropertiesSold).ToList();

    Console.WriteLine("Results in order of most properties sold:\n");
    Console.WriteLine($"{"Name".PadRight(10)} Properties Sold");
    Console.WriteLine($"{new string('-', 10)} {new string('-', 15)}");

    foreach (var realtor in realtors)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"{realtor.Name.PadRight(10)} {realtor.PropertiesSold}");
    }

    GetKeyFromUser("\nDone! Press any key to exit...");
}
```

**Sample Output**

[image]

---

**Note**

The sample code above uses a method called `GetIntFromUser` to get the number of properties sold. The reason for this is that we can't expect that the users will always enter a valid number, so we want to do some validation on it first.

The method (below) takes in a `string` that is used to prompt the user for input, and it takes an optional validation function that can be used to ensure that the value they enter is allowed (in the sample above, I specified that the value must be greater than or equal to zero).

Here is the method used in the sample above:

```
public static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt, Func<int, bool> validator = null)
{
    int result;
    var cursorTop = Console.CursorTop;

    do
    {
        ClearSpecificLineAndWrite(cursorTop, prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result) ||
             !(validator?.Invoke(result) ?? true));

    return result;
}

private static void ClearSpecificLineAndWrite(int cursorTop, string message)
{
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
    Console.Write(new string(' ', Console.WindowWidth));
    Console.SetCursorPosition(0, cursorTop);
    Console.Write(message);
}
```

Comment: `realtor.PropertiesSold = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());` come on buddy, can't trust that input :) `realtor.PropertiesSold = int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int myValue) ? myValue : 0;` good solution as well.

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Yeah, I normally use a separate method to get an `int` from the user, but this answer is focusing on combining the properties. I've updated it now, however, since it's a good suggestion. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this answer @RufusL, I'm afraid it's too complicated for me and I need to more or less justify everything I do in this project. Your code is very good but at a higher level to what I am capable of, so I would not be able to justify my use to my teacher etc but yet again thank you very much for this answer.

Comment: I understand. Take what you can from it, and throw the rest away (for now). It's tricky writing answers here, because I want to put forth good code. But feel free to ignore the `GetIntFromUser` and replace it with your `int.Parse` code. Same thing with the output formatting, if that seems complicated. You can just output `Console.WriteLine("Name " + realtor.Name + "  Properties Sold: " + realtor.PropertiesSold`);` If `OrderByDescending` is too complicated, you could write your own `Quicksort` method and use that instead (assuming you've learned how to sort an array).

Answer (score 2):

> I have stored the name and properties sold in their own separate lists, I know how to sort the number list in size order but then how do I link it back with the appropriate name?

The other answers give mostly good advice. Summing up, it is:

- Make a single list that holds instances of a class or struct that encapsulates the string and the integer.
- Instead of two lists, make a dictionary that maps strings to integers. (The strings are "keys", and the integers are "values".

However it is worth pointing out that there are also methods to answer your question directly, namely, *how do I sort one list by the elements of another list*?

**Method one**

Once you have built both lists, use `ToArray` on both of them. Then use the overload of `Array.Sort` which takes two arrays, one of keys, and one of value, but sorts both of them by the key array:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.sort?view=netframework-4.8#System_Array_Sort_System_Array_System_Array_System_Int32_System_Int32_

**Method two**

Suppose you have elements numbered 0, 1, 2, 3 in both lists.   Create that sequence of numbers:

```
var indices = Enumerable.Range(0, names.Length);
```

Now sort that sequence *by the corresponding value*:

```
var sortedIndices = indices.OrderBy(i => numbers[i]);
```

Make sure this step is clear. If we have numbers `40, 30, 10, 20` then we are ordering *the numbers 0, 1, 2, 3* by the corresponding values in this sequence, so we will get 2, 3, 1, 0.

Now we can transform that into a sequence of names!

```
var sortedNames = sortedIndices.Select(i => names[i]).ToList();
```

**Method three**

Use the `Zip` sequence operator to form a "zipper join". That is, join up the two sequences like the teeth meshing in a zipper. Then order the sequence of pairs by the number, and then extract the sorted sequence of names:

```
var sorted = names.Zip(numbers, (name, number) => (name, number))
                  .OrderBy(p => p.number)
                  .Select(p => p.name)
                  .ToList();
```

I strongly recommend that you make a study of the operations you can perform on sequences in C#. They are extremely powerful tools.

Comment: I wish you and stackoverflow were around when I was learning C in college years ago.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the dictionary to implementing this senario

```cs
 Dictionary<string, int> users = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the employee name: ");
                string name = Console.ReadLine();
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter the number of Properties Sold: ");
                int number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                users.Add(name, number);
             }

            var data = users.OrderByDescending(a => a.Value).ToList();

            foreach (var i in data)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(i.Key+" "+i.Value);
            }
```

Comment: Note that if you use a `Dictionary`, you can't enter more than one employee with the same name (but in this example that would be confusing anyway since the name is the only identifier for an employee)

Comment: Thanks for this answer but I needed to hold more data in the end so had to use a class, sorry for my poor explanation in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use structs or a dictionary. I won't give you a line by line answer because it's an assignment and you need the problem solving practice but here is the steps:

Read in the name and number like you are already. Rather than storing them in separate lists, create a new struct for each person with their number of properties sold and their name (Or put them in a dictionary key-value pair).

Then you can sort the list (or dictionary) and print it out. Each item in the list/dictionary is guaranteed to be associated with the right data if you put them in right in the first place.

Comment: Thanks, after hours of stress I finally cracked it. I ended up using a class as I needed to store more info than I originally suspected. Thank you for your answer though!