# Finding highest value in an array and matching to corresponding index location of another array for later use

Tags: c#

The contents of the arrays (student names and test scores) are pulled from a text file in this format:

> Helen Mills
>   25
>   Jake Stein
>   35
>   etc.

I have used the following code to find the highest int in `marks[]` and assign it to `topMark`, however haven't been able to figure out how to store the corresponding name as strings for `topFirstname` and `topSurname`. So in this example I would like for `int topMark = 35`, `string topFirstname = Jake` and `string topSurname = Stein`

```
int topMark = marks[0];
foreach (int value in marks)
{
    if (value > topMark) topMark = value;
}
```

Comment: What data structure are you using for `marks`? Are you using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/)?

Comment: yes i am using LINQ

Comment: See the techniques mentioned in the answers to this question; it is not exactly the same as yours but you can figure out how to solve your problem by adapting one of these techniques. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59634429/store-name-number-and-sort-in-size-order-based-on-the-numbers/59635180#59635180

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Person
{
  public string Name {get;set;}
  public int Mark {get;set;}
}

public IEnumerable<Person> ParseFile(string filePath)
{
  System.IO.StreamReader file = new System.IO.StreamReader(filePath);
  while((var name = file.ReadLine()) != null)
  {
    var p = new Person();
    p.Name = name;
    p.Mark = int.TryParse(file.ReadLine());
    yield return p;
  }
  file.Close();
}
```

Then your main logic would just be:

```
var topPerson = ParseFile(@"C:...").OrderByDescending(p=>p.Mark).First();
Console.WriteLine($"Top mark: {topPerson.Mark}");
Console.WriteLine($"Top name: {topPerson.Name}");
```

Feel free to break the name up into first/last name if you need.

Comment: Thanks i will try this.

Comment: This is great, because it creates a `Person` object for each record that you are tracking in. The `OrderByDescending` takes the guesswork out of who has top marks, but the downside is that it doesn't consider ties, but will return the first Name from the input (stable sorted).

Comment: @SunnyPatel Yes, I prefer to separate the processing from the input whenever possible.  It would be fairly easy to work with ties as well, depending on how you wanted it handled it would likely just be a slightly more complex LINQ query.