# Returning last record from database

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core

I am trying to display the last record that was processed according to the database, a client has processes that belongs to them.

So Client 1 has processes 1 & 2, and I am looking to display what the last record and when it was processed according to the process table in the database. I want to return this to a view and display in a table.

Here is what I have been trying so far:

```
 var robots = from h in _context.HeartBeat
                         join p in _context.ProcessTable on h.ProcessID equals p.ProcessID
                         join e in _context.EnvironmentTable on p.EnvironmentID equals e.EnvironmentID
                         join c in _context.ClientTable on e.ClientID equals c.ClientID
                         select new DashViewModel
                         {
                             processName = p.ProcessID,
                             environmentName = e.EnvironmentName,
                             LastRunTime = h.RecordFinish
                         };


            IEnumerable<DashViewModel> robo = robots.ToList<DashViewModel>();
```

this selects all the processes from database. there is thousands so this isnt ideal.

Comment: if you need only 1 record - order records by date (end of processing) or some id (if it is auto incremental) in descending order and take first record

Comment: @demo how do i do this in linq?

Comment: Here is example of `orderby descending` https://stackoverflow.com/a/24289779/3917754 and then just use `.FirstOrDefault()` or just `.First()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using EF Core you could use:

```
var last = robots.Last();
```

to get the last record. Or

```
var last3 = robots.TakeLast(3).ToList();
```

to get a certain number form the end.
You may want to force a certain sort with `.OrderBy(r => r.Id)` or something.