# Sort specific values inside a list through LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

Hi I currently have a list of strings with values:

```
*Item1, *Item2, Test2, Test4, *Item3, Test1, *Item4, *Item5
```

How do I re-arrange them and have all the values with asterisk to be in the first part of the list such as this while maintaining the order of the non-asterisk items:

```
*Item1, *Item2, *Item3, *Item4, *Item5, Test2, Test4, Test1
```

Comment: which criteria are you using for sort? doesn't  `list.Sort();` solve it for you?

Comment: `string[] items = {"*Item1", "*Item2", "Test2", "Test4", "*Item3", "Test1", "*Item4", "*Item5"};
var result = items.OrderBy(x=>x);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LINQ Orderby Descending Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5344805/linq-orderby-descending-query)

Comment: It's unclear if you want to order the asterisk part on simply put them first. In your example all asterix are already ordered making this special case unclear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple `OrderByDescending` will do the thing

```
var str = "*Item1, *Item2, Test2, Test4, *Item3, Test1, *Item4, *Item5";
var arr = str.Split(new char[] { ' ', ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var ordered = arr.OrderByDescending(x => x.StartsWith("*")).ToArray();
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Marking as the answer :)

Comment: This simply put the asterisk first. "_while maintaining the order of the non-asterisk items_"., perhaps imply it was only for the non-asterisk.